# Запуск приложения из Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Из Apps Script хочу запустить приложение на локальном компе

```
var pth="C:\\ee.exe" ;
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
```

........

однако стандартный создание компонента Components.classes...) не работает. Возможен ли вообще запуск приложения на локальном компе из Apps Script ?

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли это возможно, у GAS немного другое назначение

Дело в том, что Apps Script серверная технология и никакого отношения к окружению пользователя не имеет. Т.е. для взаимодействия с окружением пользователя скриптам понадобятся какие-то инструменты на стороне пользователя.

Другими словами - это вещи несовместимые без дополнительных инструментов.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/571253)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, мои извинения. Это недовольство системой SO =)

Comment: @contributorpw Да, окей ;)

Answer (score 0):

По идее это связано с Полномочиями Chrome
Т.е. Components.Classes и Components.Interfacses не инсталированы и надо их подключить типа так
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
ан не ест JS такую конструкцию